# Disable autoplay video in Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, video

Is there a way of disabling auto-play of video in Chrome? Many sites have moved to HTML5 video and so you have ads or featured videos that start automatically playing the moment the page loads.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How do I disable HTML5 player for Chrome on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125082)

Comment: Not really. I want to disable auto-play of video files, whereas that question is about disabling HTML5 video completely.

Answer (score 8):

On Android Chrome 54, turn off autoplay of media by going to **Settings - Site Settings - Media - Autoplay and Block autoplay**.

This feature is disabled if you have data compression enabled in your Android Chrome browser.

Comment: addendum: On Android Chrome 80, these settings do not exist at all. There does not appear to be any way to block media autoplay.

Comment: Chrome 99: the Media setting does not appear to exist.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Chrome 47, there's a Chrome flag that is used to turn media autoplay on/off:

> Disable gesture requirement for media playback.
>
> Disable user gesture requirement for playing media elements. Activating this will allow autoplay to work.

You can see it by going to this link: [chrome://flags/#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback](http://chrome://flags/#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback);

The default status for the flag is disabled, so autoplay should not work: you should check your Chrome version and eventually update it. I tested with version 47 and autoplay does not work unless you turn on the flag.

Other info [here](http://techdows.com/2015/12/chrome-47-lets-you-disable-defer-media-playback-in-background-tabs.html).

Comment: It's for background tabs, not the current tab.

Comment: I tested again right now and it works also in the foreground tab in Chrome 47... Have you tested it? Could you share the link you tried?

Comment: Try visiting this [page](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/prince-george/12057507/William-and-Kate-choose-Montessori-nursery-in-Norfolk-for-Prince-George.html). The ad on there autoplays and the speaker icon appears in my notification bar.

Comment: I've just tried this on a variety of pages - in particular smh.com.au - and it appears to block the playback on all videos, thankfully.  That said, contrary to the OP, it was Disabled initially and I had to Enable it to disable the auto-playback.  The description states "User gesture requirement for playing media elements. Disabling this will allow auto-play to work".

Answer (score 3):

Chrome for Android doesn't have an option to disable autoplay. My solution is: Switch to Firefox.